# Smooth 3d transforms in Phonegap Android

Tags: android, cordova, css-transforms, iscroll4

I'm trying to make an application with a gallery using Phonegap. In it, I am using jQuery and iScroll4.

I need to make the effect of increasing the size of the central element.To do this, I set the item parent property -webkit-perspective: 1200px and the item itself [-webkit-transform: translateZ (150px); -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d.](http://jsfiddle.net/CEzjc/3/) It looks good in Chrome, but does not work on Android 2.2 (Samsung Galaxy) and 2.3 (Kindle Fire). On Android 3.0 (Motorola Xoom) it works, but jerky.

I tried to use [-webkit-transform: scale (1.14)](http://jsfiddle.net/CEzjc/6/). It works on all devices, but it still jerks. Variants with change height / width or zoom also did not give good results.

How can I make this effect smoothly on all (Android) devices?

I will be grateful for any informative answer.

Comment: 3D transforms are not very good on Android. If you can avoid them you should. Go add your star to this issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=25147

Comment: I'd like to avoid them, but how can I make this effect in another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this, CSS3 scale using absolute positioning

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
img {
    position:absolute;
    top:50px; left:50px;
    height:60px; width:80px;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.2s ease;
}
img:hover {
    top:35px; left:30px;
    height:90px; width:120px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <img src="image.png" />
</body>
</html>
```